# Imap loading mailbox contents performance | php-imap | laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I am coding my own mailbox system.

I want to load the INBOX folder. I am already paginating/limiting results at 40 per page, but the performance is still really bad compared to real webmail providers.

I already have done some research and it seems that the performance is good if I do not load flags and attachments (especially attachments).

See this results for 40 emails:

```
// 3 sec~
$selectedFolder->query()->whereAll()->setFetchFlags(false)->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()

// 3 sec~
$selectedFolder->query()->whereAll()->setFetchFlags(true)->setFetchBody(false)->leaveUnread()

// 9 sec~
$selectedFolder->query()->whereAll()->setFetchFlags(true)->setFetchBody(true)->leaveUnread()
```

The huge difference comes from `setFetchBody(true)`, but I need the body if I want to show a quick info whether the email has attachments, so what to do? How mail providers achieve such a good performance?

The only solution I can come up with is: Cache the emails in a DB table. Maybe run a cronjob to update the cache and fetch emails from the DB instead directly, is this how it is done?

Comment: I would build a db structure and add in the contents of the emails/attachments to that, its much quicker to access local information than to lookup them each time ;). Now have a cron job that polls every min to download any message that have not previously been downloaded. Then when you actually read a message send a message back to the mailbox to say it has been read and any other functionality you require

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is performance. And there are different ways to achieve it:

1. **Cache** - Try to cache everything that your application repeats several time. Api results, content, files.. At the same time you should be careful with it. There is always dilemma between speed and storage capability.
2. **Load only what you need**. No need to download content, attached files, history when you show only list of mails. Title, subject and sender is enough for the end-users. Other part of email could be showed when client press "Show email" button
3. **Pagination**. You do not need to load all mails.
4. **Parallelism** You could run 4 queries in parallel. In theory, you can process 4 times more emails.

And this list is just the top of the big iceberg. There is no limit to perfection, and optimization can be endless. But I think for a start, this should be enough to get the result at least close to other mail services.
Also, I would suggest you to look at the source code of other projects on the github. There are a lot of them where you can highlight additional ideas and tricks for optimization:

- [Mailspring](https://github.com/Foundry376/Mailspring)
- [Mailu](https://github.com/Mailu/Mailu)
- [Mailpile](https://github.com/mailpile/Mailpile)
- [nylas-mail](https://github.com/nylas/nylas-mail)